# Unpacking a list in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am using the [Analemma](https://github.com/liebke/analemma) library to make some svg figures. To make more complicated figures I wanted to break up the svg into components that could be generated in a different function and passed to the main `svg` function. Simple enough idea, right?

Well I keep getting tripped up when I try to pass a list of values and am not really sure how to get around the issue.  In python you would be able to unpack the list using `*list` and I am wondering what an equivalent would be in clojure.

If there is no equivalent I wold appreciate any pointers about how to accomplish the same goal.

```
(use 'analemma.svg)

;set a line
(def oneline (->  
               (line 0 0 100 100)
               (style :stroke "#006600" :stroke-width 3)))

;create an SVG by passing one or more line elements works fine
; this works 
(svg oneline)
; so does this
(svg oneline oneline)

; but if i have a list of lines created in a different function  i have a problem
(def manylines (repeat 5 oneline))
; this will not work
(svg manylines)

;I've tried the following but this doensn't work eaither becasue it mushes the list all together
(svg (apply concat manylines))
```

thanks
zach cp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe you are looking for something like

```
(apply svg manylines)
```

this would produce same result as

```
(svg oneline oneline oneline oneline oneline)
```